# Android calculator: button for decimal place

Tags: android, calculator

I am new to Android development and currently learning to design for a basic calculator app. I have already self designed the layout, but sourced Main Activity codes from different websites for the operations for 0 to 9, `+, -, *, /` and after incorporation, they work fine.

However, I do want to further modify the MainActivity with decimal point function. 
While integer can be shown properly to the screen using "current = current * 10 + number", eg 53 = 5*10+3;

I am thinking applying the same approach for decimal point with a loop function, the idea like this:
1. current = current + remaining if dot button is pressed
2. create an integer i, i increases by 1 once any numerial button is clicked 
3. so that when e.g. input 5.3, i =1, it will = 5 + 3/(10^i) = 5.3
4. 5.3 loop to here, then when e.g. input as 5.39, now i=2, it will = 5.3 + 9/(10^i) = 5.39

**QUESTION >>**
**Yet...really...I am so fresh that I do not know how to design the coding for the decimal button, would there be anyone can suggest the code?** first ignore the following addons where errors to be detected (such as delete the second dot if the dot is input twice or more, adding `0` in front of `.` if say, `.5` is input)

The button id is as follows, and once clicked to refer to DecimalClickEvent
      Button b_decimal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.decimal);
      b_decimal.setOnClickListener(new DecimalClickEvent(???));}

Many many thanks in advance!! The codes are attached below for reference and your comments:

=========================MainActivity.java=====================================

```
package com.trial.newcalculator;

import java.io.Serializable;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressLint("ParserError")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    State s;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        s = new State();

        int[] opNumbers = new int[] { 
                R.id.zero,
                R.id.one,
                R.id.two,
                R.id.three,
                R.id.four,
                R.id.five,
                R.id.six,
                R.id.seven,
                R.id.eight,
                R.id.nine,     
        };

        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ansEditText);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10;i++){
            final Button button = (Button) findViewById(opNumbers[i]);        
            button.setOnClickListener(new NumberClickEvent(textView,s,i));          
        }

      int[] opButtons = new int[] { R.id.add, R.id.subtract, R.id.multiply, R.id.divide };
      State.Operation[] states = new State.Operation[] {
                State.Operation.PLUS, 
                State.Operation.MINUS,
                State.Operation.MULTIPLY, 
                State.Operation.DIVIDE};

        for(int i = 0; i < opButtons.length;i++){
        Button b_op = (Button) findViewById(opButtons[i]);
        b_op.setOnClickListener(new OperationClickEvent(textView, s, states[i]));
        }

// Memory functions
        int[] memButtons = new int[] { R.id.MC, R.id.MR, R.id.Mdeduct, R.id.Mplus};
        State.Operation[] mstates = new State.Operation[] {
                State.Operation.MEMORYCLEAR, 
                State.Operation.MEMORYCALL,
                State.Operation.MEMORYMINUS, 
                State.Operation.MEMORYPLUS};

        for(int i = 0; i < memButtons.length;i++){
        Button b_mem = (Button) findViewById(memButtons[i]);
        b_mem.setOnClickListener(new OperationClickEvent(textView, s, states[i]));
        }
//  Memory functions    

//decimal
//      Button b_decimal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.decimal);
//      b_decimal.setOnClickListener(new DecimalClickEvent(textView, s, "."));   
//decimal

        Button b_eq = (Button) findViewById(R.id.equal);
        b_eq.setOnClickListener(new EqualClickEvent(textView, s));

        Button b_op = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ac);
        b_op.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                s.clear();
                textView.setText(s.getDisplay());
            }
        });               
    }      
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstanceState.putSerializable("STATE", s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Serializable serializable = savedInstanceState.getSerializable("STATE");
        if(serializable!= null){
            s = (State) serializable;
        }
    }

    public void onPause(){
         super.onPause();
    }

}
```

===============================State.java==================================

```
package com.trial.newcalculator;

import java.io.Serializable;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class State implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1231231231231233L;
    public TextView output;
    public enum Operation {     
        PLUS,       
        MINUS,      
        MULTIPLY,       
        DIVIDE,     
        MEMORYPLUS,
        MEMORYMINUS,
        MEMORYCALL,
        MEMORYCLEAR,
    }   
    public enum IOState{        
        INPUTTING,      
        DISPLAY_RESULT, 
    }   
    private Double accu = null; 
    private double current = 0; 
    private double memory = 0;
    private Operation currentOp = null; 
    private IOState currentState = IOState.INPUTTING;   
    public Operation getCurrentOp() {       
        return currentOp;   
    }   
    public void setCurrentOp(Operation currentOp) {     
        if (currentState == IOState.INPUTTING){         
            if (accu != null && this.currentOp != null ){calculateResult(); 
            }
            else{accu = Double.valueOf(current);current = 0;
            }
        }
        this.currentOp = currentOp;     
        if (currentState == IOState.INPUTTING){
            currentState = IOState.DISPLAY_RESULT;
        }   
    }   
    private void calculateResult() {
        double res = accu.doubleValue();
        switch (currentOp) {
            case PLUS:
                res += current;
                break;
            case MINUS:
                res -= current;
                break;
            case MULTIPLY:
                res *= current;
                break;
            case DIVIDE:
                res /= current;
                break;
            case MEMORYPLUS:
                memory += current;
                break;
            case MEMORYMINUS:
                memory -= current;
                break;
            case MEMORYCLEAR:
                memory = 0;
                break;
            case MEMORYCALL:
                current = memory;
                break;
        }
        accu = Double.valueOf(res);
        current = 0;
    }
    public void number(int number) {
        if (currentState == IOState.INPUTTING){
            current = current *10 + number;
        }
        else if(currentState == IOState.DISPLAY_RESULT){
            currentState = IOState.INPUTTING;
            current = number;
        }
    }
    public String getDisplay() {
        String res;
        Double d = getCurrentDisplayValue();
        double doubleValue = d.doubleValue();
        int intVal = (int)doubleValue;
        if (intVal == doubleValue){
            res = Integer.toString(intVal);
            }
        else{
            res = d.toString();
            }
        return res;
    }
    private Double getCurrentDisplayValue() {
        Double d = accu;
        if (currentState == IOState.INPUTTING){
            d = Double.valueOf(current);
        }
        return d;
    }
    public void clear() {
        accu = null;
        currentState = IOState.INPUTTING;
        currentOp = null;
        current = 0;
    }

    public void equal() {
        if (accu == null || currentOp == null){
            return;
        }
        calculateResult();
        currentState = IOState.DISPLAY_RESULT;
        currentOp = null;
        current = getCurrentDisplayValue(); 
        }
}
```

====================OperationClickEvent.java===============================

```
package com.trial.newcalculator;

import com.trial.newcalculator.State.Operation;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

final class OperationClickEvent implements OnClickListener {
    private State s;
    private TextView textView;
    private Operation op;


    public OperationClickEvent(TextView textView, State s, State.Operation op) {
        super();
        this.op = op;
        this.s = s;
        this.textView = textView;
    }


    public void onClick(View v) {
        s.setCurrentOp(op);
        textView.setText(s.getDisplay());
    }
}
```

=================EqualClickEvent.java=======================================

```
package com.trial.newcalculator;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

final class EqualClickEvent implements OnClickListener {
    private State s;
    private TextView textView;


    public EqualClickEvent(TextView textView, State s) {
        super();
        this.s = s;
        this.textView = textView;
    }


    public void onClick(View v) {
        s.equal();
        textView.setText(s.getDisplay());
    }
}
```

======================NumberClickEvent.java==================================

```
package com.trial.newcalculator;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

final class NumberClickEvent implements OnClickListener {
    private int number;
    private State s;
    private TextView textView;


    public NumberClickEvent(TextView textView, State s, int number) {
        super();
        this.number = number;
        this.s = s;
        this.textView = textView;
    }


    public void onClick(View v) {
        s.number(number);
        textView.setText(s.getDisplay());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating new classes for negative click event and doublezeroclickevent,  i suggest you to get their id's and do the proper functionality when the particular button is clicked .

Comment: yes yes...thanks for your advice...sorry for being as a beginner and it's just some personal perference for making things into separate classes to make the program shorter and easier to debut...yup...but really cannot work out how to design classes for the 1) decimal 2) +/- 3) doublezero

Comment: For a double zero, try to multiply the particular value with 100 and display it when the particular double zero is clicked

Comment: And coming to the decimal one..
When the user clicks the decimal button append the "." to the number (thinking as it is a string) and again parse it into Float.
Try it.

Comment: actually how to "parse"? 

now is that when number buttons are pressed, it is through the integer variable called "number" and add to the double variable "current" in a way that

current=current*10+number

would it be practical to make a loop fcn such that: 
1. current = current + remaining if dot button is pressed 
2. create an integer i, i increases by 1 once any numerial button is clicked 
3. so that when e.g. input 5.3, i =1, it will = 5 + 3/(10^i) = 5.3 
4. 5.3 loop to here, then when e.g. input as 5.39, now i=2, it will = 5.3 + 9/(10^i) = 5.39

if to use "parse", need to redevelop all?

Comment: I think we are having something like Float.parseFloat(string value);
Once check it

Comment: thanks! these days i have redeveloped the coding such that to implement the method as float.parseFloat(string value). It is much simplier without maths involved and is definitely a better method.

Answer (score 0):

Each OnClickListener can be a default anonymous class, that will be triggered only by one button.
So no need to name them "NegativeClickEvent", "DoublezeroClickEvent", etc.

You can keep a boolean variable if the "." was pressed, and accept another one only if not.
If you want a usable calculator, you need a "backspace" button as well. So note that the dot may be deleted. (need to keep track of its placement).

For the leading 0, you can use a simple "if dot was pressed first, insert 0.".

There are many ways to implement what you want, but to keep it simple, just handle the cases you need to handle.

Other ways to implement this may include Double.parseDouble(s) with catch (NumberFormatException e) on each key pressed, or using a double as your buffer, and using the buttons to perform mathematical operations on it directly (such as multiply by 10 and adding the new digit on each button press) - this will ensure input validity without the need to parse String, but it's more complicated to implement.

Comment: thanks a lot for your advice!! yes i am thinking of adding memory function, backspace function and +/- function too.

Comment: the code above is using Current = current *10 + number, this maybe for what you saying above...yet just a matter want to know more, would it be work for input having decimal places later on? would it then change to write as say, if no dot, current = current * 10 + num, if contain dot, current = current + num /10? (but dont know further decimal places to be input..) thanks a lot anyway for your advice!!

Comment: you'll need to keep track of decimal place to add current/Math.pow(10,place). There are more complexities if you support backspace. Other approach is to use decimal point only for rendering and apply it after completing the edit, and until than use integer + a variable for the decimal placement.

Comment: Note my second suggestion to use String (StringBuilder actually ) to edit the number, and validate it on each step using Double.parseDouble(s), accepting every new char only if no NumberFormatException was thrown. It's very easy to implement, with no math involved.